# Can't understand how to decode M68K binary code

Tags: disassembly, 68000

I want to make a disassembly of the m68k compiled binary myself and make an emulator.
I've disassembled the binary file into a text file with a thirdparty tool `m68k-linux-gnu-objdump -b binary -m m68k:68000 ...` to have a better vision of what is going on in the binary

Here I have an instruction:

```
0604 0320       addib #32,%d4
```

From [this](http://goldencrystal.free.fr/M68kOpcodes-v2.3.pdf) table I see that `addi` function has the next binary scheme:

```
0000 011 0 <S> <M> <Xn>
```

and my instruction has representation of:

```
0000 011 0 00 000 100
```

Which means I have `addi` operation with size (8 bits), addressing mode "data register" and the register is encoded to be D4.
Ok, addib with destination %d4 but what does this data column on the right side mean?

I see that the second word (2 bytes of data) in the disassembly is 0x0320 where the last 4 bits 0x20 actually my #32 literal in decimal. But what is this 0x03 in the middle? I've seen some other addi instructions in the disassembly and everywhere there was a 4 bits of something in the middle and the last 4 bits were my number in hex.

I'm probably not taking the last column of the table into account "data" but I failed to understand how to interpret it.

For the example above the table says, data type - "any type" + immediate mode but what is this "any type".
The size of addi instruction said to be any b/w/l in the second (green) column of the table. Are these three things like blue data's first sub-column(B,W,/), green size column (B/W/L), and pink  sector of the scheme (00 - B, 01 - W, 10 - L) related? I'm completely confused
And the problem I don't understand the boundaries of the instructions. I've seen some instructions that were maximum 16 bits long (as shown in general schema for each operation) but there are "brief extension words" and "full extension words", what the book says about them I can't get completely. The only thing I probably understood is that the first 16 bits of the opcode is "Single Effective Address Operation Word" and that is.
This is my first approach in trying to understand such a low level of programming

Comment: "Any type" just means the instruction can be used with bytes, words, or longs, depending on which one you chose (in this case you chose byte.) You'll notice that `ori ___, ccr` shows a `B` in this column, this means that your immediate must be able to fit in a byte or it's not valid. This is for the simple reason that the CCR register is only 8 bits.

Comment: @puppydrum64 for `ori` there are all B/W/L available. You may have confused it with "ANDI to CCR"

Comment: If you're using `ori` to a typical `Dn` or `An` register, yes. But `ccr` is 8 bits in size.

Comment: It's ok, I assume the code is already correct. I don't yet understand the pattern of recognition of further (additional) data for instruction. As you can see from my example, I understand how to recognize "addib" opcode from 0x0604 (just compare bit by bit with opcode description from the manual or table) but what happens next, I can't get why we know from 0x0604 that there's a value 4 bits after the end of "addib" instruction (after address of 0x0604 + 4 bits)

Answer (score 3):

Do what the CPU does with the first byte of the immediate data word of a byte size instruction: Ignore it.

By encoding the two size bits as "00", you told the CPU that you want to add an 8-bit immediate value to the byte-size part of d4 - That means, the upper byte of the immediate data word is not used, but still the 68000 will only read instructions word-wise. Thus, the upper part of this data word is simply "don't care" - You can put anything in there without changing the effect of the instruction, because the CPU won't use it. (Thus, the actual value "3" you see there in your case is irrelevant and probably just some random value left over from the assembler)

If you encode the instruction as ".w" (that is, you want to do a 16-bit add), the upper byte of the data word becomes relevant. If you encode the very same  instruction as .l (32-bit add), the assembler will add yet another word to the instruction and put the 32-bit immediate in those 2 words.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't sure if that extra `3` meant something or not. I didn't think so, but I've never felt the need to dive into the binary representation of m68k instructions.

Comment: I doubt any reasonable assembler will insert random values into unused parts of the data part. It is possible that `0604` is actually the data part of the previous instruction, or that this is entirely pure data. But this is impossible to say without more context.

Comment: @chtz $0604 is actually the opcode of the instruction - Nothing random here. "03" in the $0320 data word is the random thing. I tested the same thing with my 68k assembler - it seems to clear the unused 8 bits of the data word, so it's definitely an assembler thing. I wold argue a "proper" assembler should behave like that.

Comment: @tofro What I was trying to say is that without context you can't be sure that `0604` is actually the beginning of an instruction. It could be that OP actually has something like `lea $0604,a0; btst d1,-(a0)`, i.e., `41f8 0604 0320`.

Comment: @chtz If the OP would have sent off a monitor or disassembler program randomly on some program code at some random address, I would agree. But a disassembly from *objdump* should be properly aligned.